# How to purposely have a code path not return an int value in C#

Tags: c#, .net, error-handling, return, return-value

**Problem :**
I believe I am missing some major point in programming here. I want to create methods which have some code paths which return nothing. Eg for error handling.

**Example:**

    `public static int calculateArea(int width, int length){
        if(length < 0 || width < 0){
             //don't want to return anything as negative distance is impossible
             //Execute my error handling here
        }
        else{
            int area = length * width;
            return area;
        }
    }`

**The question:** Quite simply, is there a way to override the fact that you must return a value in all code paths?

**Potential solutions** I have seen online one solution where the error handling code paths return a particular value so you know to ignore it. However, this seems a very unstable solution.
I am happy to restructure my code if there is a better way to write these types of methods.

**Why this question is original:** I think this question is original as I have been unable to find a specific answer online or in the SO forums.

Comment: `The question: Quite simply, is there a way to override the fact that you must return a value in all code paths?` Quite simple **NO**, `I think this question is original` No, you need just read more about c#/.Net

Comment: You could throw an exception.

Comment: @juharr If you throw an exception you don't have to return a value?

Comment: What *would* the function result be in the 'alternative codepath' if such was allowed? 0? A random integer? Would it make more sense if the function could return null (vai `int?`) or throw an exception after/instead of 'error handling'? Most of the above are valid, but the behavior has to first be *defined* - then the code can be written to fulfill it.

Comment: btw, if you throw an exception in your if clause, then you can skip the else block and make your code more readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There're two statements that in C# are considered to *return* a method: `return` and `throw`.

In your case, if a distance is negative should throw an `ArgumentException` or `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

In the other hand, since this is about *parameter validation* you should take a look at [*code contracts*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264808(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public static int CalculateArea(int width, int length)
{
    Contract.Requires(length > -1  && width > -1, "Distance must be positive");

    int area = length * width;

    return area;
}
```

Comment: @mhenkel Design by contract is a very expressive and enjoyable way of defining your code requirements with code! :)

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Its seems pretty cool but getting some weird as errors in the procces

Answer (score 2):

Use a Nullable Int instead: `int?` and `return null` when you don't want to return a usable value.

Comment: For me, this is almost the same as returning -1 or who knows what.

Comment: Yea thats true, thats not a good solution, since you would have to recheck the result of that method yet again ...

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is throw an exception there.

```
Throw new Exception("Length and width cannot be negative.");
```

As soon as you put that in you'll see your compiler error go away because on that code path the function isn't returning - it's exiting with an exception.

You can also be more specific with your exception type, perhaps using an `ArgumentException`.

An exception indicates that the function cannot operate on the given parameters, which is accurate. You don't want to return `null`. If you do that then anything that calls the function has to check the value to see if it's null. And if it's null, what does that mean? Or the code still throws an exception, but now it's a baffling `NullReferenceException`. And if the result gets passed around a bit before being used the exception might be nowhere near the function, making it even more confusing. But if the exception is thrown when the function is called with invalid parameters then it will be much easier to tell where the problem is.

Comment: I feel like it's worth putting some real emphasis on how much of a bad idea it is to throw `Exception` instances instead of some derived type. you're basically saying to clients that they either CAN'T do anything about it (how would you know that?) or that they have to catch ALL possible exceptions, including ones that are totally non-related to passing invalid arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You could throw an exception and either catch it directly or at some other point in your code. Here is an quick, I think self-explanatory example.

Some Examples:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87cdya3t(v=vs.110).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173163.aspx

```
public static void randomCaller()
{
  try {
    int a = calculateArea(-1, 500);
  } catch(NegativeDistanceNotPossibleException e) {}
}        

public static int calculateArea(int width, int length){
          if(length < 0 || width < 0){
             //don't want to return anything as negative distance is impossible
             //Execute my error handling here
             throw new NegativeDistanceNotPossibleException("this is not possible");
          }
          else{
            int area = length * width;
            return area;
          }
        }

public class NegativeDistanceNotPossibleException : Exception {
  public NegativeDistanceNotPossibleException() {}
  public NegativeDistanceNotPossibleException(string message) : base(message) {}
  public NegativeDistanceNotPossibleException(string message, Exception inner) : base(message, inner) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to return an int?, then return null in that branch. Otherwise you could have a ref parameter & not modify that value if the length or width is negative

If you absolutely must return an int from this method & don't want to return anything, then the only option is to throw an uncaught exception. ArgumentOutOfRangeException would be a good choice

Comment: This appears to be the best-structured answer so far. Most people have had very similar approaches so thanks. I did consider using a ref parameter, but I decided against it as I didn't want to add a random area variable where I was implementing the method.

Comment: I must disagree. Null values are generally problematic - you have to check results for nulls. If you try to get an area with an invalid height or width then it should throw an exception. If you call a function to get an area and the result is "null" then what do you do with that null?

Answer (score 0):

If you didnt want throw exceptions, best way to return some class or stucture, displaying operation result. Example:

```
 public class OperationResult
 {
    public bool Success {get;set}
    public string ErrorMessage {get;set}
    public int Result {get;set} //use it if success true
 }
```

So u can handle error text and fact that some error has occured, otherwise you can use operation result

Comment: A class requires more memory allocation than an int, now lets think about your write a program that has millions of classes stored instead of integers. I always try to write performance oriented and clean code. So throwing an exception is better in my opinion. (You could even log exceptions pretty easily in one spot of your application, wouldnt even have to use try, catch for that to work and keep your program running.)

Comment: @mhenkel,  If you want to get better perfomance , use assembler or C++, C# is for bussiness apps, that need support and clean code. My code logic is better for supporting other programmers , so my code is cleaner than you. Throwing exceptions is also hard perfomance operation, more harder than allocating some bytes in heap for class in return value. If u can avoid exceptions throwing , avoid it. I prefer use exceptions in unhandled scenarios, not for bussiness logic. Summary : error execution flow depends of application kind.